# Setting \textwidth when using newlfm

Tags: margins, newlfm

I want to set the width of the text in a letter that uses the `newlfm` package. Take the following basic example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{newlfm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 
\setlength{\textwidth}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

Something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something

\end{newlfm} 
\end{document}
```

The width of the text is not set to `2cm`. But if `\begin{newlfm}` and `\end{newlfm}` are removed the width of the text is set to `2cm`. But since I want to use `newlfm` to format my letter removing those commands doesn't solve the issue properly.

I have read the `newlfm` manual [1] to my best but have been unable to find a solution to this issue.

[1] http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/manual.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written in sections **4. Spacing commands** and **4.1 Horizontal spacing** of the manual you have to use

```
\newlfmP{textwidthsize=2cm}
```